# how to dynamically add Serial Number to every Split String that is appended to HTML <div> tag

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, timer

***functionality:***

There are 10 different Strings-> "name,score,timer", hence I have split each string to each individual element and append to the  tag.

***Issue:***

I am able to split and append the split String to  tag, however, I am unable to dynamically set Serial number 1 to 10 for each appended element to the table  tag.

Hence, the 10 different Strings when split will look like this:

1. Name     Score     Timer
2. Name     Score     Timer
3. Name     Score     Timer
4. Name     Score     Timer
5. Name     Score     Timer
6. Name     Score     Timer
7. Name     Score     Timer
8. Name     Score     Timer
9. Name     Score     Timer
10. Name     Score     Timer

Issue is I am stuck on how to set the serial number to each line of the split element.

***What has been done***

```js
$(function() {
  //data are the 10 individual Strings that have been retrieved from database
  var playerList = data.split("@");

  var innerList;
  for (i = 0; i < playerList.length; i++) {
    innerList = playerList[i].split(",");
    console.log(innerList[0] + "|" + innerList[1] + "|" + innerList[2]);
    $("#Player_Name").html(innerList[0]);
    $("#Player_Score").html(innerList[2]);
  }
});
```

```html
<table id="Rugby_Scoreboard">
  <tr>
    <td>
      <div id="Serial_Number" style="z-index:50; position:absolute; top:440px; left:100px; font-size:160px; font-family:'OpenSans-Light'; width:1080; color:#fff;">
        <font face="OpenSans-Light"></font>
      </div>
    </td>

    <td>
      <div id="Player_Name" style="z-index:50; position:absolute; top:440px; left:500px; font-size:160px; font-family:'OpenSans-Light'; width:1080; color:#fff;">
        <font face="OpenSans-Light"></font>
      </div>
    </td>

    <td>
      <div id="Player_Score" style="z-index:50; position:absolute; top:440px; left:1195px; font-size:160px; font-family:'OpenSans-Light'; width:1080; color:#fff;">
        <font face="OpenSans-Light"></font>
      </div>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: What error do you get for these 2 line items? `$("#Player_Name")..html(innerList[0]);
    $("#Player_Score")..html(innerList[2]);
 ` (Hint............)(Another Hint F12)(One More Hint 'console tab)

Comment: @zer00ne, it was a typo, supposed to $("#A").html();

Comment: It's typed twice on two different lines, so I assumed it was intentional. (Hint: Edit typos in question or you are going to have to explain that it's a typo to people constantly)

Answer (score -1):

Use the index value from the for loop.

$("#Serial_Number")..html(i+1);